# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound how can I fix it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm making a discord bot for my server, but my codes continue to give me this error. My goal is to have a class with some commands, but I always get the error "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound". These are my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class General_commands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def message(self, ctx:commands.context, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
        await ctx.channel.send('message')
        

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


bot.add_cog(General_commands(bot))

bot.run(token)
```

Do you know what I do wrong? If something is unclear you can simply ask :)

I've already tried to use examples saw in github but I didn't menage to solve my problem :(

If I put the command outside the function, with some adjustments it works, but would preferably have it in the class.

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Have you verified the methods are spelled correctly and that they exist?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal `CommandNotFound` doesn't occur on a line of code written by the user, it's raised internally when someone in Discord invokes a command that doesn't exist in your command mapping

Answer (score 0):

Cog loading became asynchronous in 2.0, your code is very outdated. Read the migration  guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

> ext.commands.Bot.add_cog() must now be awaited.